# Is there a way to convert flex grammar file to textmate grammar json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flex-lexer, textmate

I have been working on a new language and wanted to make a syntax highlight extension for VS Code. I am currently working on the compiler and the lexer is made using flex and the parser is hand-written. I am wondering is there a way to generate a TextMate grammar file from an existing flex grammar file. I've searched the Internet and found no answer.

Comment: you can write a Flex-Bison app for that

Comment: I think the short answer is no. I've spent a bit of time looking at the conversion of Flex .l's to Antlr lexer rules. If you ignore the fact that Flex allows arbitrary actions for a pattern, it's easy to extract the patterns, then convert those in a naive manner to whatever syntax you like. I don't know how easy it would be for TextMate, but it seems possible. I was never fond of TM because the rules are regular, not context-free, so I would chose an LSP server implementation instead.